# How to set Netgear FVS338 as "Interior Router"?

Tags: networking, router, subnet, configuration-managment, netgear-router

I got a NETGEAR FVS338 ProSafe VPN Firewall Router. I planned to use it as Interior Router that seating in back of my Sagemcom Gateway F@st 5366 TN-A.

I'm running quite few business application servers in my home office. The Sagemcom networks configured as:

- Local IPv4 Address    10.0.1.1
- Local Subnet Mask 255.255.0.0
- Local Ethernet Mac address    xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
- Public IPv4 Address   58.105.xxx.xxx
- Public Subnet Mask    255.255.240.0
- Default Gateway   58.105.160.2
- Primary DNS Server    198.142.152.164
- Secondary DNS Server  198.142.152.165

When **FVS338** plugged into sagemcom network, configured it as:

[image]

From the above image you can see, I had created a different network (10.0.2.0/24) for Netgear FVS338 LAN under Sagemcom network (10.0.1.0/24). Wan side (Broadband configure) has IP address 10.0.1.92 seating sagemcom networks as Netgear gateway IP.

- I tried to add the router to my MacOS Host in Sagemcom network to access subnet 10.0.2.0/24. by run [sudo route -n add -net 10.0.2.0/24 10.0.1.92]
- Then, I set up NetGear FVS338 [Security] -> [Firewall] -> [Attack Checks] -> [WAN Security Checks] by ticking [Respond to Ping on Internet Ports].
- Then, I ping 10.0.1.92 and 10.0.2.1 success

Then, When I tried to configure [LAN WAN Rules] by adding an [Inbound Services] to expose host 10.0.2.203 that seat in NetGear FVS3338 network.

[image]

I tried to ping the exposed host under Netgear FVS338, but I never get it through.

I log in to Netgear FVS338 from the command line by USING CLI, and ping 10.0.2.203 from Netgear FVS338 self, the ping works fine, but I ping 10.0.2.203 from the WAN side (Sagemcom network), I never get it through.

Any idea?

Comment: Unless you have disabled Network Address Translation on the netgear router this will not work. ICMP (ping), unlike TCP/UDP, does not use ports which is a requirement for NAT/PAT. And when NAT is on, IP addresses on the netgear network are not routable from the WAN side. Instead you would usually use port triggering/forwarding to expose specific services available on the netgear network to the Sagecom network (Netgear WAN side), assuming NAT is on, and then you reach those services from the sagecom network using `10.0.1.92`, not the IP address of the destination device on the netgear network.

Comment: @Appleoddity, thank you for your advice. I tested, it works fine for me.